# Does $X_{n}=o_{p}\left(Y_{n}\right)$ imply that $P\left(Y_{n}=0\right)=0$ for all $n$?

Tags: probability, convergence

Suppose that $X_{n}=o_{p}\left(Y_{n}\right)$. Does this imply that $P\left(Y_{n}=0\right)=0$ for all n ? Or only, e.g., that $P(Y_n = 0)\rightarrow 0$?

I guess it is a matter of definition. If $X_{n}=o_{p}\left(Y_{n}\right)$, then that means that $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}$ converges to 0 in probability. But if $Y_n$ can take value 0 with positive probability for some $n$, then I guess $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}$ is not technically a random variable for that $n$ (because it is not a map from $\Omega$ to R but rather to extended R)? Is that true? If that is true, then can we still talk about probability limit of the sequence?

Comment: Since the little-o notation expresses something about a limiting value of a sequence, it makes no assertions at all concerning any finite set of values in the sequence.  BTW, it isn't obvious that $\Pr(Y_n=0)\to 0:$ could you explain why that might be so?  This might shed some light on what you mean by "$o_p(Y_n)$" when $Y_n$ is a sequence of random variables (as it seems to be here) instead of the usual sequence of *positive real numbers,* as is customary in the definition of this notation.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. First, I will delete the part about "obviously true", since I don't want to spread bad information. The reason why I think it is true is because if it does not go to 0 in the limit, then $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}$ has positive probability to be infinity, or undefined (if $X_n$ also is 0), which is not allowed for a random variable because random variables must as far as I know take real number values.

Comment: Those remarks are not quite correct.  $X_n/Y_n$ may have *zero* probability of being infinite even when $Y_n$ converges to zero.  One simple example is the case $X_n=Y_n$ (where $\Pr(Y_n=0)=0$).  Also, good accounts of measure theory permit random variables to have infinite values.  (See Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* for instance.)  But let's return to the heart of the matter: please explain what you mean by "$o(Y_n)$" when the $Y_n$ are random variables.

Comment: @whuber That is very helpful. Thank you for all your help here and everywhere on stackexchange (I learn so much from your answers). As for what I mean, it is more that I have seen this notation elsewhere and assumed there was a well-defined notation. Now I understand that my confusion came from that there is no agreed-upon definition when $Y_n$ are random variables. Just understanding that is a big help to me. Now I know if I use that notation for random variables, I should first clearly define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $X_n = o_p(Y_n)$, when we are not disallowing $Y_n = 0$, is probably best expressed as stating, for all $\epsilon > 0$ that
$$
P(|X_n| \le \epsilon |Y_n|) \to 1, \qquad (n \to \infty). 
$$
The "almost-sure" version would be $X_n = o(Y_n)$ with probability $1$, which is equivalent to 
$$
P(|X_n| \le \epsilon |Y_n| \text{ eventually}) = 1
$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$.

With the definitions clear, we now see that neither $P(Y_n = 0) = 0$ nor $P(Y_n = 0) \to 0$ hold. In fact, we can have $Y_n = 0$ almost surely; we just need $X_n = 0$ almost surely as well.

To make things more interesting, let's add the stipulation that $|X_n| > 0$ almost surely. In this case it is possible for $Y_n = 0$ to occur infinitely often when $X_n = o_p(Y_n)$; just take $Y_n = n |X_n|$ with probability $(n-1)/n$ and $Y_n = 0$ otherwise. But we should have $P(Y_n = 0) \to 0$ in this case, because $Y_n = 0$ implies $|X_n| > \epsilon |Y_n|$.

For the almost-sure version, this does imply $P(Y_n \ne 0 \text{ eventually}) = 1$, because this is a subset of $[|X_n| > 0 \text{ for all $n$, and } |X_n| \le \epsilon Y_n \text{ eventually}]$, which has probability $1$.

Comment: Thank you. This is quite helpful. Do you have a reference where $X_n = o_p(Y_n)$ is defined in the same way you suggest? (I'm interested more in convergence in probability in case that is helpful for reference)

Comment: @EmpProc I don't have a reference, it just strikes me as the obvious thing to do. If you were going to bother talking about the case where we wanted to allow $|Y_n| = 0$ with positive probability, I can't see any other way of proceeding. The fact that $|X_n| / |Y_n|$ allows for division by zero is more a quirk of the definition than a statement about the concepts underlying big-O.

Comment: OK makes sense. I have now found some references that use your definition. For example, these notes use similar idea: http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/8112/notes/ohpee.pdf